# Can't find login Activity

Tags: android, dependency-injection

I've had an "On/Off" sessions with Android for the past three years, climaxing with an app which can be described as a ["Big ball of mud"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud).

In order to avoid such travesties, I decided to use [Android Bootstarp](http://www.androidbootstrap.com) as a basis for expansion and a guide for good working conventions.

I think I managed to grasp the basic logic behind dagger (which is used for injecting modules and classes throughout the app), but as stupid as it may seem, I can't seem to grasp how/where or when the login Activity is called:

- The "home" activity (the one with the launcher/home intent filters assigned) is called CarouselActivity, and is used to show all the content you get after login (user, news and checkins fragments). No reference to the login activity.
- The login activity is called BootstrapAuthenticatorActivity
- The only reference to it is in the BootstrapModule class, where it's added to the "injects" member of the @Module annotation.
- Also, here's a cryptic quote from the AndroidManifest.xml file:

  ```
  <activity
      android:name=".authenticator.BootstrapAuthenticatorActivity"
      android:excludeFromRecents="true" >

      <!--
          No intent-filter here! This activity is only ever launched by
          someone who explicitly knows the class name
      -->
  </activity>
  ```

This isn't helpful...

Ok, so no direct callback, no intent filters, and my IDE's "Find Usage" button doesn't help either(shows usages of the class only withing the same class...)

This leaves me with two possible explanations:
1. This has something to do with injections, which I fail to understand.
2. Something else altogether, which I completely missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After rummaging through just about every single class in the project, and another couple of hours spent on traceview, I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-bootstrap/CPBIBg0vbtM/) on the Android Bootstrap Google Group.

Bootstrap uses Android's built in  authentication framework, which here means that there's a service defined in the app which checks whether there are saved API keys or login details, and if not it starts the login activity.

So to sum it up, here's a nice list partially describing the authentication lifecycle:

1.The login Activity is called from an intent the BootStrapAccountAuthenticator class addAccount method (which extends the [AbstractAccountAuthenticator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html) class)

2.The BootStrapAccountAuthenticator is added to the AccountAuthenticatorSerivce, which returns the authenticator when onBind(); is called (the service has an intent filter for `android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator`)

4.Another class, called ApiKeyProvider, calls the AccountManager.getAuthTokenByFeatures(), which in turn binds to the AccountAuthenticatorSerivce) and returns the key it got.

5.BootstrapServiceProvider returns in its getService(); method a new BootstrapService created with the key retrieved by ApiKeyProvider (BootstrapService is a POJO implementing HTTP requests using kensawiski's http-request library).

6.Each fragment class (a total of three in this case) calls the BootstrapServiceProvider.getService(); method in the onCreateLoader method.

That's it.

Regarding the usage of dagger, everything is injected retroactively from the fragments themselves down to, and including, the AccountManager.
I assume this could allow for relatively modular code (for example, you could swap out the ApiKeyProvider with a different one).

I hope this is even remotely clear, and maybe even possibly of help to anyone.

I might come back later and "refactor" this answer...